# Cannot assign value of type 'AppDelegate' to type 'CLLocationManagerDelegate?'

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I import `CoreLocation`, then add `locationManager.delegate = self` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and `let locationManager = CLLocationManager()` out of it.

But I have this error in AppDelegate. What do I wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to make your AppDelegate conform to `CLLocationManagerDelegate.`

```
class AppDelegate: UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {}
```